# Target an element in an iFrame using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I want to type and get some info from an iframe, within a Site. but my issue is that I cant read any elements within the iFrame. 
It logs that it loaded the content frame, but cannot target any element after that.

The waitForSelector is "null"

also when I tried to skip the waitForSelector the i get the error message, cannot read property 'type' of null.

```
await page.waitForSelector("body > div.body.clearfix.container_20 > div.main.grid_12 > iframe");
            // need to target IFRAME

            const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[class="orderFrame"]');
            const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
            console.log('iFrame load succesfull')

            // paste ORG
            const OrgInput1 = "#Netui_Form_0 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=text]";
            await frame.waitForSelector(OrgInput1);
            await frame.type(OrgInput1, orgNumber, {delay:100});
            // click Next
            await frame.waitFor(2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't access the frame content (frame is null). It might be an [OOPIF](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes). Try launching chromium/puppeteer with `--disable-features=site-per-process`.

Comment: hmm.. I get what it means, however what does this do in question of security etc. will the page im scraping find out?

Comment: @zwappy edited the link to point to OOPIF's page. It's part of the site isolation effort so cross-site iframes won't share a process with the website. Unless the website or frame are actively trying to perform attacks (e.g. Spectre), you should be fine.

Comment: thank you, maybe a dumb question, but do i need to enable it again or does it only disable for that instance?

Comment: @zwappy it's a command line argument that puppeteer passes to chromium before launching it. so every time you launch chromium (or puppeteer.launch), this argument must be passed